# grepl function does not recognize the euro symbol from scraping directly

Tags: r

I am doing a scrape from the web "fotocasa" in Spain.

I download the item that contains the price doing the following:

```
url<-"https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/casas/madrid-provincia/todas-las-zonas/l/3?latitude=40.415&longitude=-3.7104&combinedLocationIds=724,14,28,0,0,0,0,0,0"
idealista <- html(url)
price<-idealista %>%
  html_nodes("span") %>% #item de precios
  html_text()
```

And I have a vector similar to this:

```
>price
...
[97] "hace 1 hora"                                         "198.500€"                                           
 [99] "198.500€"                                            "€"                                                  
[101] "4 habs."                                             "128 m²"                                             
[103] ""                                                    ""                                                   
[105] ""                                                    ""                                                   
[107] ""                                                    "hace 1 hora"                                        
[109] "6.000.000€"                                          "6.000.000€"                                         
[111] "€"                                                   "5 habs."                                            
[113] "641 m²"                                              ""                                                   
[115] ""                                                    ""                                                   
[117] ""                                                    ""                                                   
[119] "hace 1 hora"                                         "1.800.000€"                                         
[121] "1.800.000€"                                          "€"                                                  
[123] "Ha bajado 100.000€"                                  "5 habs."                                            
[125] "800 m²"                                              ""                                                   
[127] ""                                                    ""                                                   
[129] ""                                                    ""                                                   
[131] "hace 1 hora"                                         "690.000€"                                           
[133] "690.000€"                                            "€"                                                  
[135] "Ha bajado 410.000€"                                  "3 habs."                                            
[137] "320 m²"                                              ""                                                   
[139] ""                                                    ""       
...
```

I want only the values that contains the euro symbol, so what I do is:

```
>price<-price[grepl("€",price)]
```

But what I obtain is:

```
> price
character(0)
```

Because It did not recognize the euro symbol. If I create a vector which contains the euro symbol and I use the function `grepl`, It works!, but If I tried directly from the scrapping it does not work.

## Question

What should I do to make the "`grepl`" function recognizes this symbol directly from scraping?

## Result:

The result must to be something like this:

```
> price
 [1] "198.500€"             "198.500€"             "6.000.000€"           "6.000.000€"           "1.800.000€"          
 [6] "1.800.000€"           "Ha bajado 100.000€"   "690.000€"             "690.000€"             "Ha bajado 410.000€"  
[11] "2.450.000€"           "2.450.000€"           "Ha bajado 450.000€"   "1.350.000€"           "1.350.000€"          
[16] "1.200.000€"           "1.200.000€"           "2.275.000€"           "2.275.000€"           "2.200.000€"          
[21] "2.200.000€"           "540.000€"             "540.000€"             "975.000€"             "975.000€"            
[26] "3.750.000€"           "3.750.000€"           "1.100.000€"           "1.100.000€"           "1.800.000€"
```

Comment: Works for me. My guess would be an encoding issue on your part.

Comment: `grepl("€", price)` works for me too. By the way, instead of `price[grepl("€",price)]` you can do `grep("€", price, value=TRUE)`

Comment: @Cath It depends on the encoding `grep("€", price, value=TRUE)#
character(0)`

Comment: Thank you @Cath. As said akrun in the answer, It must to be a problem with the system. In any case, I think it's best to work with unicode.

Comment: @akrun the comment about `grep` instead of `grepl` was a general one, but of course, if `grepl` does not work, `grep` won't work either, as both the code lines I gave are meant to give the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the unicode

```
res <- price[grepl("\u20AC",price, perl = TRUE)]
length(res)
#[1] 91
```

as the OP's code gives

```
any(grepl("€",price))
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Wow! It works with this. Thanks a lot!. Do you recommend me ever use unicode for these "rare" symbols?

Comment: @HenryNavarro  If you find some symbols are not supported in your system, you can try with the unicode.  As mentioned by  Roman Luštrik it works for him, probably because of the locale.  My locale is different

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer, I will give it as right when stackoverflow allows me, It says me that I must to wait 5 minutes.

Comment: Akrun, my friend, do you know where I cand find a equivalence between text and unicode? Because I have a similar problem with this symbol: "m² "

Comment: @HenryNavarro  You could check these links [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refunicode.html) or [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) or [here](https://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character)

Comment: @HenryNavarro  Perhaps for the specific case [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/33a1/index.htm)  i.e. `grep('\u33A1', '㎡')#
[1] 1`